# How does Ansible determine what version of a module to use (Windows/Unix)?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-module

Ansible Core has a `setup.py` module for Unix systems (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/setup.py). This is responsible for "fact gathering".

Ansible Windows has a `setup.ps1` module for Windows systems and mimics the behaviour in `setup.py` to some extent (https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.windows/blob/main/plugins/modules/setup.ps1).

When running:

```
- name: Setup
  setup:
```

Ansible correctly identifies which module to run.

My question is, how does Ansible determine which module to run?

I cannot find any action plugins that would be called beforehand that would determine which module to run.

Furthermore, when I attempt to mimic this behvaiour with a custom module I receive errors when running with Unix. This is because it attempts to run the `.ps1` version of the module rather than the `.py` version.

Comment: Does [Where does Ansible DSL get translated to either Powershell or Python?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/17327/6017) answer your question?

Comment: "_How does Ansible determine which module to run?_", in general Ansible don't do that, since the [specific Windows Modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/list_of_windows_modules.html) are named with a prefix `win_`. So there is no need to decide for Ansible since within the YAML it is stated if should run on Windows or not. See also [Using Ansible and Windows](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/windows_usage.html).

Comment: Yes, the general notion is to use `win_` like you say but for some Ansible "modules" like with `setup`, this isn't the case and yet Ansible still works fine for both UNIX and Windows systems.

Comment: @U880D Unfortunately, that does not answer my question. I did however find `meta/runtime.yml` under a collection which has plugin redirects e.g.,: `setup.ps1:
redirect: ansible.windows.setup`. This might be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

Under the collection you can create a `meta/runtime.yml` file in which you define:

```
plugin_routing:
  modules:
    [module_name].ps1:
      redirect: [module_name_in_other_collection]
```

This then allows you to ues `[module_name]` and Ansible will determine where to look for the `.ps1` variant of that module.